# Services do not work in Preview after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: preview, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina, when selecting text from pdf files in Preview and try to use services, the text is not passed into services. For example, I have enabled shortcut for "Look Up In Dictionary", but when I press the shortcut key the selected text does not show up in dictionary.

I found the following log related to the error:

`2019-11-19 21:17:44.907 Preview[41744:3943423] Object <PVPDFView: 0x7fead0e7eba0> could not or did not write the selection to the pasteboard in preparation for a service request`